# Convert string into format array without remove coma PHP

Tags: php

I have string :

```
$string = "'id_konversi_aktivitas' => 'f4d943e7', 'nim' => '180218038'"
```

And I will convert to array like this :

```
$data = array($string);
```

But the result is like this :

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(87) "'id_konversi_aktivitas' => 'f4d943e7', 'nim' => '180218038'" }
```

I want result like this :

```
array(2) { ["id_konversi_aktivitas"] => "f4d943e7", ["nim"] => "180218038" }
```

Comment: You need to write a parser, PHP doesn't have anything built-in that will do this.

Comment: Can you change the string format? It's almost like JSON, why don't you use that so you can use `json_decode()`?

Comment: `array($string)` will make an array with exactly one item in it. It won’t construct a string from `array()` and the contents of `$string` and evaluate the result as PHP literal (that’s what you seem to expect). This is an impractical format to have array data stored as. You should change your initial string format to something that can easily be turned into an array, like JSON.

Comment: If the keys and values never contain `'` characters, you can write a regular expression and use `preg_match_all()` to extract the keys and values.

Comment: PHP has something built in that does this. But I won't name it here because it's very dangerous to use.

Answer (score 0):

there is no core PHP function to achieve what you are looking for. You can try in the following way.

```
$string = "'id_konversi_aktivitas' => 'f4d943e7', 'nim' => '180218038'";
$arrayStr = explode(',', $string);
$myArr = [];
foreach ($arrayStr as $arr) {
    $eachArr = explode('=>', $arr);
    $myArr[trim($eachArr[0])] = $eachArr[1];
}
print_r($myArr);
```

Comment: What if one of the values in `$string` has a comma in it?

Answer (score 0):

I made a function specifically for this problem, I hope it helps you out.

```php
function stringToArray($string) {
    $output = [];
    $array = explode(",", $string);
    foreach($array as $elem) {
        $item = explode("=>", $elem);
        $newItem = [
            trim(str_replace("'", "", $item[0])) => $item[1]
        ];
        array_push($output, $newItem);
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Here's how I used it

```php
<?php  
$string = "'id_konversi_aktivitas' => 'f4d943e7', 'nim' => '180218038'";

function stringToArray($string) {

    $output = [];

    $array = explode(",", $string);
    foreach($array as $elem) {
        $item = explode("=>", $elem);
        $newItem = [
            trim(str_replace("'", "", $item[0])) => $item[1]
        ];
        array_push($output, $newItem);
    }
    return $output;
}

$data = stringToArray($string);
print_r($data[0]["id_konversi_aktivitas"]);

// >> 'f4d943e7'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions instead of a simple `explode` makes parsing a bit safer. `preg_match_all` returns the result in a form that returns the desired array with `array_combine` without a loop.

```
string = "'id_konversi_aktivitas' => 'f4d\'943e7', 'nim' => '180218038'";

preg_match_all("~'(.+?)' *=> *'(.+?)'(,|$)~",$string,$match);

$array = array_combine($match[1],$match[2]);

var_dump($array);
```

I added a ' to the string from the request for testing purposes.

Demo: https://3v4l.org/6YO8Q